# Function parameters issue with variables and strings

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a simple [farming game](https://squirrel-314.github.io/vegetable-dash/Game/index.html), and am having trouble with repetitive code. I have to make a different harvest function for each item, and as more vegetables are added it gets harder to make changes. I have attempted to solve this with function parameters, but I am getting this error.

```
index.html:12 Uncaught ReferenceError: peas is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:12)
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="plot" id="plot1">
  <button id="grow1" onclick="plantPeas()">Grow Peas!</button> 
  <button id="harvest1" onclick="harvest(peas, 1)">Harvest Peas!</button>
</div>
```

And here is the JavaScript

```
let plotStatus = {
   peas: "empty",
}
function harvest(veg, num) {
   plotStatus.veg = "empty";
   document.getElementById("grow" + num).style.opacity = "1";
   document.getElementById("harvest1" + num).style.opacity = "0";
   document.getElementById("harvest1" + num).style.zIndex = "-1";
   produce.veg++;
}
function plantPeas() {
   // Set timeout for growingPeas and  readyPeas
   setTimeout(growingPeas, 2000); // Change the status if peas to growing in 2 seconds
   setTimeout(readyPeas, 5000); // Change the status of peas to ready in 5 seconds
   // Remove the grow peas button
   peaPlntBtn.style.opacity = "0";
}
```

I know it expects peas to be a variable but it does not work as a string either.

Thank you.

Comment: `onclick="harvest('peas', 1)"` — the code in the "onclick" attribute value must be valid JavaScript code.

Comment: `onclick=harvest(plotStatus.peas, 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to simplify you could simply not use the ID at all and just refer to the parent object and a data attribute.

```js
let plotStatus = {corn:"empty",peas: "empty"}
let produce = {corn : 0,peas: 0}

function plant(el){
   plot = el.parentNode;
   veg = plot.dataset.produce;
   
   switch(veg){
      case "peas" : plantPeas();break;
   }
}

function harvest(el) {
   plot = el.parentNode;
   veg = plot.dataset.produce;
   
   plotStatus[veg] = "empty";
   
   plot.querySelector(".grow").style.opacity = "1";
   plot.querySelector(".harvest").style.opacity = "0";
   plot.querySelector(".harvest").style.zIndex = "-1";
   produce[veg]++;
   
   console.log(produce, plotStatus);
}
```

```html
<div data-produce="peas" class="plot">
  <button class="grow" onclick="plant(this)">Grow Peas!</button> 
  <button class="harvest" onclick="harvest(this)">Harvest Peas!</button>
</div>

<div data-produce="corn" class="plot">
  <button class="grow" onclick="plant(this)">Grow Corn!</button> 
  <button class="harvest" onclick="harvest(this)">Harvest Corn!</button>
</div>
```